# How to distinguish a domain and a hostname in python

Tags: python, hostname, urlparse

A domain is something like this: **google.com, yahoo.com**. It also have a whois record

A hostname is something like this: **m.google.com, www.google.com, images.google.com**

A domain can have very interesting TLDs and ccTLDs: **google.co.uk, google.academy, google.xxx**

A hostname can be also like this: **mail.services.1.google.com, xxx.google.com**

Here is the question: I have a string variable and i want to decide that if the value is a hostname or a domain. Is there a clever way to distinguish them in python?

Answer (score 0):

You already seem to know how to differentiate between them.

use `urllib.parse` to break down the string and then write your own logic to decide.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: Additionally, you can use a TLD list @ https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db to distinguish parsed domains from hostnames.

Comment: urllib.parse gives us only hostname, not domain. i tried it. the TLD list that u wrote only contains TLDs not ccTLDs! The key problem is in here is the ccTLDs. Otherwise u do not include the last part after splitted by point

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. We can do this with tldextract package.

```
from tldextract import tldextract

test_str = 'mail.google.co.uk'
te_result = tldextract.extract(test_str)
domain = '{}.{}'.format(te_result.domain, te_result.suffix)
print('domain: {}'.format(domain))
print('is_hostname: {}'.format(test_str != domain))
print('is_domain: {}'.format(test_str == domain))
```

Answer:

```
domain: google.co.uk
is_hostname: True
is_domain: False
```